# Meteor reset on Heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku, meteor

What is the best way to redeploy an alpha version on Heroku, and perform a `meteor reset` for the server mongo fixtures to be re-executed on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find a good solution. So I need to go in my heroku mongohq interface, and manually remove all collections, then restart heroku.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this with a custom method for any hosting(only debug, not in Production):

in /server/reset.js

```
 Meteor.methods({
   resetear: function() {

     Collection1.remove({});
     Collection2.remove({});
     //And Update Any Collection 3, Flush array embeded
     Collection3.update({},{$set:{'usersenrol':[]}},{'multi':true});

   }
});
```

And then, in the Client Console:

```
Meteor.call('resetear')
```