# How do I run Meteor shell in Heroku?

Tags: unix, heroku, meteor

I've deployed my Meteor app to Heroku using the https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor buildpack.  My Meteor is v1.0+.

How do I access a server console to my app? Normally on my local dev machine I would run `$ meteor shell`.

Similarly, how can I `meteor reset`?

Thanks

Comment: Similar q here, they didn't seem to get a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962602/meteor-reset-on-heroku

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used the oortcloud meteor buildpack, or a fork of it, the build uses a production mode build of meteor. `meteor shell` is a development tool and not available for use in production mode.

This is a tradeoff. You could theoretically use use a development mode instance in production but you would have terrible performance. Meteor in development struggles to cope with > 10 users. In production mode the figure is much larger.

`meteor reset` on the other hand clears the database of the development mode database. To clear up your database log into your database using `mongo` and drop all the collections. Alternatively run use `db.dropDatabase();` (in mongo)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Basically, I want these tools to troubleshoot on my staging environment - hence wanting dev type tools on a production-like environment.  A server console would be wonderful in this case. Are you saying that I can't do this?

Comment: @Alveoli it's not possible to do this unless you use development mode in your production environment. That is running your app on heroku using `meteor` as you would on your development computer. Keep in mind if you do this you won't have production quality performance. In production mode the best you can do is use a tool like kadira or tail logs for errors.